# pl/sql trigger error : exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having a tough time understanding what is wrong with my pl/sql trigger.
The error is :
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TRG_LATE_RETURN", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.TRG_LATE_RETURN'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

My trigger is as follows:

```
create or replace trigger trg_late_return
before update of DETAIL_RETURNDATE, DETAIL_DUEDATE on TY_DETAILRENTAL

declare 
  temp_date DATE:= SYSDATE;
  temp_due_date DATE:= SYSDATE;

BEGIN
  select DETAIL_RETURNDATE
  into temp_date
  from TY_DETAILRENTAL;

  select DETAIL_DUEDATE
  into temp_due_date
  from TY_DETAILRENTAL;

  IF temp_date is null
  THEN
    update TY_DETAILRENTAL
    set DETAIL_DAYSLATE=null;
  END IF;

  if temp_date <> null
  THEN
    if temp_date = trunc(temp_due_date) + 1
    then
      update TY_DETAILRENTAL
      set DETAIL_DAYSLATE=0;
    end if;

    if temp_date > trunc(temp_due_date) + 1
    then
      update TY_DETAILRENTAL
      set DETAIL_DAYSLATE = DETAIL_RETURNDATE - DETAIL_DUEDATE;
    end if;  
  end if;

END;
/
```

New to SQL and PL/SQL so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I doubt `TY_DETAILRENTAL` has exactly one row, so your `select . . . into` statements are not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your queries or updates have filters (where clauses) so you are working on the entire table - that can't be what you intended. You are trying to get *all* of the value of those columns into scalar variables, which can only hold a single value.

The trigger is also against the same table you're querying and updating, which suggests you actually meant this to be (or need this to be) a row level trigger, not a statement level trigger.

That means you need to add `for each row` to the definition, and instead of requerying and updating the table, you can operate on the `new` pseudorecord that is available for row level triggers.

You also can't use `<>` to compare with null; you're already using `is null`, and the opposite of that is `is not null`. Although you could also just use `else` here.

So this might be what you wanted:

```
create or replace trigger trg_late_return
before update of detail_returndate, detail_duedate
on ty_detailrental
for each row
begin
  if :new.detail_returndate is null
  then
    :new.detail_dayslate := null;
  else
    if :new.detail_returndate = trunc(:new.detail_duedate) + 1
    then
      :new.detail_dayslate := 0;
    elsif :new.detail_returndate > trunc(:new.detail_duedate) + 1
    then
      :new.detail_dayslate := :new.detail_returndate - :new.detail_duedate;
    end if;  
  end if;
end;
/
```

You can refer to the updated columns value with `:new` when comparing them too, so you don't need the local variable copies of those values. (You can look at the pre-update values with `:old` too, but that doesn't seem to be needed here).

Changes you make to the `new` pseudorecord are used when the actual matching row in the database is finally updated.

[Read more about the new/old pseudorecords](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955), and about [triggers in general](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm).

Comment: Thanks! That solved that error.  Still having issues when I attempt to update but most likely something I did wrong, will look at those links to further understand pl/sql.

Comment: You won't update the table from the trigger; you modify the `:new` pseudorecord field matching the table column instead.